# AWS Lambda equivalent of Express req.on("close") and req.on("end")

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

The nodeJS / Express code below enables us to to detect whether the user closes their connection before `response.end();` is called. I am trying to recreate something similar in AWS Lambda.

Is there any way of using the [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) object passed to the Lambda handler to achieve this?

I'm also looking at [serverless-express](https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express) but would prefer to avoid using an external library, if possible.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  let count = 0;
  let gracefulClose = false;
  req.on("close", function () {
    if (!gracefulClose) {
      console.log('Connection closed before res.end() called');
    }
  });
  req.on("end", function () {
    gracefulClose = true;
    console.log('res.end() called');
  });
  setInterval(() => {
    if (count === 3) {
      res.end();
    } else {
      count += 1;
    }
  }, 1000);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with AWS Lambda, since Lambda never has the actual network connection, it just has some details about the request. API Gateway is handling the actual HTTP connection.

Comment: Ah good insight thanks @MarkB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Lambda functions are always invoked through the 'invoke' API. This might be via an Application Load Balancer or an API Gateway, but it's always the case. Lambda functions don't know about the client connection and don't know if it's been closed early.

Comment: Nice to have a canonical answer thanks @MarkSailes